# issue regarding jquery basic slider and jquery UI tab?

Tags: jquery

I'm not able to use the both Jquery slider and jquery UI tab..
At the time only one is working either slider or tab..Is there any order to maintain while keeping the scripts in the webpage...

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title> My website</title>
    <!--slylesheet-->
    <link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="respon.css">
    <!--flexslider-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function() {
                $('.flexslider').flexslider(){
                  animation: "slide",
                  controlsContainer: ".flexslider-container"
              });
            });

        </script>

        <!--jquery UI tab-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="tab.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    </html>
```

Comment: where is the problem? it seems to be working in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ptsRd/1/)

Comment: I m not able to know which script will come first ...